# Javascript: How to check if element is visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, visible, zepto

i'm using the lightweight zepto.js framework and now I need to test if an element on the page is visible or not … this my case:

A button triggers the function `show_guides()`.

```
function show_guides() {
    $('#guides').toggle();

    if ( $('#guides').is(':visible') ) { // does not work
        //$.cookie('guides_visible', 'true');
        console.log("visible");
    } else {
        console.log("invisible");
        //$.cookie('guides_visible', null);
    }
}
```

If the `$('#guides')` are visible I want to save a cookie and if they are not I want to get rid of it.

However zepto.js doesn't support selectors like `:visible` so I have to find a different way.
Any ideas how to do that?  Right now I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

In the zepto documentation i've read this …

> For basic support of jQuery’s non-standard pseudo-selectors such as
>   :visible, include the optional “selector” module.

But I have no idea how to include this.

Anybody out the who could help me out here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"But I have no idea how to include this."* The same way you load any other JavaScript file. Include [this file](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/selector.js) after you loaded zepto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the display CSS property:

```
 function show_guides() {

        $('#guides').toggle();

        if ( $('#guides').css('display') == 'block' ) { 
            console.log("visible");
        } else {
            console.log("invisible");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not work if an ancestor is hidden. For example, an image inside a hidden div would return 'block', even though it is not visible because it's container div is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
     style.display="block";
```

and

```
     style.display="hidden";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check visibility:visible/hidden, or  display:block/none

```
$('#guides').css('visibility') == 'visible'
$('#guides').css('display') == 'block'
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to check visibility you can just use this

```
  function visible(elem){
    elem = $(elem)
    return !!(elem.width() || elem.height()) && elem.css("display") !== "none"
  }
```

taken straight from the zepto selectors plugin. Otherwise you can just include the selectors module from https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/selector.js as Felix Kling suggested