# Get all html controls visible to the user?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How might one go about getting all controls visible to the user?

```
<div id=dataform>
  <div>
    Name
    <input type=text id=name class=entry>
  </div>

  <div>
    City
    <input type=text id=city class=entry style="display:none;">
  </div>

  <div style="display:none;">
    <label for=nocontact>nocontact</label>
    <input type=checkbox id=nocontact class=entry>
  </div>

  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for=phone>Phone</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type=text id=phone class=entry>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div>
    <select id="keys">
      <option value=1>1</option>
      <option value=2>2</option>
      <option value=3>3</option>
  </div>
</div>
```

Neither "city" nor "nocontact" are visible to the user.

```
document.getElementById("dataform").querySelectorAll("dataform > entry ???? ");
```

Or some other method to get all controls, inputs, that are visible (not just inputs, but selects, textarea, etc).  Could add a class to each, as shown and grab all, but how to determine or get just those that are visible to the user.  The nocontact checkbox wouldn't be, so ignore it.  I put the table in there to demonstrate that the control is not always a direct child of the div in which it resides.

I'm afraid that cycling through them all and tagging them with a class or a data attribute is the only way and that pretty much sucks.  FYI: not using jquery or other framework on this.

Comment: Just query for all elements and filter out the ones with style.display set to none, if that's all you mean by visible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get only visible element using pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612141/get-only-visible-element-using-pure-javascript)

Comment: Similar answer to below - would get where control has a display or visibility is explicitly set on the control, but would lose those that are not visible-to-the-user because a parent is not shown.

Comment: The answer Arber linked to may not have a satisfactory answer, but it's essentially the same question.  There are also several other questions that are materially the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if element is visible in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669786/check-if-element-is-visible-in-dom)

Comment: (No not really, but the question is the same.)

Comment: It might be the same question, but when looking for an entirely different result that suggests that one or both of the questions should offer more clarity to increase the distinction.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "proper" way to do this, in part because it's unclear what "visible" is supposed to mean in the first place.  jQuery (version 3.4.1) does it like this:

```
jQuery.expr.pseudos.visible = function( elem ) {
    return !!( elem.offsetWidth || elem.offsetHeight || elem.getClientRects().length );
};
```

...which is great for certain definitions of "visible", but it doesn't check whether an element has "visibility" set to "hidden", or if it's scrolled off the screen; it mostly just checks for `display:none` (including on parent elements).

Comment: That would be effective, I think, to get stuff that's within the viewport, but setting visibility:hidden or display:none wouldn't pick up and if either were set on a parent, it also wouldn't work.

Comment: @Erick This does catch `display:none`, including if it's set on a parent.  In that case the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` will both be 0.

Comment: @Brilland that's an interesting idea.  I'll play with it.  Thanks.

Comment: Whoops, this doesn't actually check if an element is scrolled off the screen; it pretty much *only* checks for `display:none` on the element or any parent.

Comment: It works for me.  I'm not worried about visibility within the viewport, but generally on the page.  I'm using it and it works.  :-)